# SQL query involving specific count with distinct

Tags: mysql-workbench

I have these tables:

- person (id primary key, name)
- money (acct primary key, loaner)
- loan (id primary key, acct)

How would I create a SQL query that shows for each loaner the names of persons who took more than four loans from that specific loaner? And I want the 4 persons that he loaned to be different with each other.

```
SELECT 
    p.id, p.name, m.loaner, COUNT(*) 
FROM 
    person p 
INNER JOIN 
    loan l ON p.id = l.id
INNER JOIN 
    money m ON l.acct = m.acct
GROUP BY 
    id, name, lower
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) = 4
```

With this query you can find the first part of the question - what should I add?

Comment: Tip of today: qualify all column names, also in the GROUP BY.

Comment: Give some sample data and expected output.

Comment: Could you explain why we have the condition: I. person A took more than 4 loans from loaner B, and II. 4 persons that B loaned different from each others? What does those means? So confusing... Do you mean B must loaned 4 different persons, and each of them must took >= 5 loans from B, means B must loaned more than 20 times is necessary condition?

Comment: brah...i asked a simple question.I want the loaners who loaned money to exactly 4 different people which means if i loaned the same guy 4 times for example it will count as 1 person.The data i give are more than enough considering i even gave you a code that works fine and finds how many times i loaned to someone(someone being a different guy or the same guy)

Comment: Your query is invalid...

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: my query works fine cause i have used it a banch of times.If u cant answer dont comment.The only thing it needs is the use of distinct which i cant do thats why i asked.

Comment: Your query is invalid. It should raise error **column ambiguous** when group by id: l.id or p.id. And your query means that it only get persons who loaned more than 4 times from one loaner. not `I want the loaners who loaned money to exactly 4 different people` as you said `i asked a simple question`

Answer (score 0):

I would try this out and see what happens :D

`SELECT distinct * 
 FROM person as p_loaner_detailed 
 WHERE p_loaner_detailed.id in (
  SELECT loanerId
  FROM (
   SELECT p.id, p.name, m.loaner as loanerId
   COUNT(*) 
   FROM person p 
   INNER JOIN loan l 
   ON p.id = l.id
   INNER JOIN money m 
   ON l.acct = m.acct
   GROUP BY id, name, loanerId
   HAVING COUNT(*) > 4 
  )
 )`